# How to retrieve JSON data from post request using python cgi

Tags: python, json, post, cgi

I have built a python server-side script which is required to retrieve a small JSON from the body of a post request.

The request body is of the form - `{name : value}` only.

I have tried using `(cgi.FieldStorage()).getvalue(...)` but to no luck. Can you please let me know how to extract such a JSON from the post request sent to it.

Answer (score -1):

Step1: make sure your server supports CGI programming

Step2: The scripts to be executed should be in the /var/ww/cgi-bin directory of the HTTP server. Make sure this is location of the script

Comment: I have the server set up and the script in the mentioned location. However, I don't know how to retrieve the json (of the type {name : value}) from the request body using python. Please let me know how to retrieve the json from the request body using python code.